# How to create dynamic html element base on array vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I would like to create input element base on some condition please help me to do in best practice to resolve it.

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in sections">
  <input :type="item.type" placeholder="item.type">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/170zvw2L/1/

if we have dropdown value takes in it automatically.

Thanks

Html should create automatically if possible to change json please guide need best solutions for this

Comment: Here is the [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/cmuq1ab6/) result. Though, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by this way...

Comment: As we have different type of form elements. i.e `input`, `select`, `textarea` and so on ... You can bind the type dynamically for input elements but for dropdown and textarea, You have to add the if condition based on the type.